# Overloading a method with an optional parameter type in Swift

Tags: swift, overriding, option-type

Can you resolve this `Ambiguous use of 'y'` error in the following code?

```
let x = 1

func y(_ x: Int) -> Int {
  return x
}

func y(_ x: Int?) -> Int? {
  return x
}

let z: Int? = y(x)
```

```
OptionalOverload.playground:5:6: note: found this candidate
func y(_ x: Int) -> Int {
     ^

OptionalOverload.playground:9:6: note: found this candidate
func y(_ x: Int?) -> Int? {
     ^
```

I would simply expect the compiler to choose the `func y(_ x: Int) -> Int` method in this scenario, since `x` is *not* optional.

Comment: I fixed it by removing _ from one of the function signatures "func y(x: Int) -> Int", but practically I would also like to know detail reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the compiler tries to resolve the overload by looking at the input argument type rather than the annotated return type and for the input argument type, the version taking the non-Optional parameter is the more specific and hence the compiler is trying to take that overload.

You can help the compiler take the correct overloaded version by declaring the input argument as an Optional rather than annotating the return value as an Optional.

```
let x: Int? = 1

func y(_ x: Int) -> Int {
  return x
}

func y(_ x: Int?) -> Int? {
  return x
}

let z = y(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be dependent on the version of Xcode, or perhaps the type of project. I just tried it in a Mac command line tool in Xcode 12.1 and it did not complain.

I also don't get an error in a playground (also with Xcode 12.1)